# Auto populating data, depending on selection

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

hoping for some help here.

I have a SharePoint List my team are populating. What I'd like to happen is, when they pick a particular Store, it populates a specific region in the adjacent field.

For instance, Stores A, B and C are in Region 1. Stores D, E and F are Region 2. If in the Choice field they choose Store B, the Region field will auto-populate with 'Region 1'.

I have all the Stores and their corresponding Region in a separate SharePoint list. Is what I'm asking possible?

Thank you in advance for any help or advice.

Best regards

Comment: If you are using classic experience SharePoint, you can add a script into your list's editform/newform to achieve this functionality. But, the limitation with this approach is that it won't work when using the 'Quick Edit' feature.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than copying or populating that value automatically, since you have the "gold source" of Store and corresponding Regions in your Store List, when you setup the Lookup field in your Team's list to give them a lookup list of Stores to choose from, configure it to pull in "Additional Fields", and choose the "Region" field from your Stores List.
[image]

The users won't see the Region on their Item entry Form, but the current Region value will get pulled into your team's list automatically based on the chosen Store.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the below sample code for cascading drop down list in SharePoint -  this code will give you the heads on then accordingly you can customize it.

```
 <script src="https://site name/jquery.min.js"></script>  

<script src="https://sitename/jquery.SPServices.min.js"></script>  

<script type="text/javascript">  

$(document).ready(function ()  

{  

    $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns(  

    {  

        relationshipList: "Employee",  

        relationshipListParentColumn: "Company",  

        relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",  

        parentColumn: "Company",  

        childColumn: "Employee",  

        debug: true  

    });  

});  

</script>
```

For details implementation as an example, please refer the below article :

[Cascading of Lookup Dropdown Fields on SharePoint 2013 and Office 365](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/cascading-of-lookup-dropdown-fields-on-sharepoint-2013-and-o/)