# Auto-populate list columns

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

My title is deceptively simple but what I need it to do may not be. I just wasn't sure how to title this. Here's what I'm looking to do: track that someone viewed an HTML5 eLearning stored in SharePoint. My thought is to put a link at the end of the training that will launch an InfoPath form associated with a list in SharePoint (2013). However, the challenge is that I want the form to already have the name of the eLearning populated in the a field called Release Name (this field is mapped to a column in the list with the same name). I don't really want the learner to complete anything in the form. Just click the button at the end of the eLearning that launches the form which states the name of the eLearning they clicked from...then they click "Submit" on the form and SP captures their name and date. I'm wondering if the trick is code in the URL to launch the InfoPath form? BTW, I'm using Adobe Captivate to create the eLearnings. Maybe this is too much to ask...IDK. Thought I'd put it out there.

Comment: This sounds like a SharePoint equivalent of a Rube Goldberg machine.

Comment: You'd probably be better off creating a script editor webpart that uses the JavaScript Object model to read values from the query string and creates an item in a list behind the scenes.  Then your eLearning can just have a link to this page with the name of the eLearning in the querystring.  You could even put a scripteditor webpart directly on the buillt-in NewForm.aspx:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25161246/pass-value-to-newform-aspx-via-querystring/25161351#25161351

Comment: Here is an example of auto populate of list column data like cascading Dropdown list :https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/275636/85808

Comment: Thank you everyone for your suggestions. Very helpful.